# Vue.js random image img v-bind

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get a random image when the page is loaded.
I cant see why this isn't working... anyone? It works when running a it as a fiddle, but not on my vue-cli with its dev server.

```
<template>
  <section>
    <img v-bind:src="selectedImage" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    images: [
      'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/200x140',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/200x100'
    ],
    selectedImage: ''
  },
  created () {
    const idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.images.length)
    this.selectedImage = this.images[idx]
  }
}
</script>
```

EDIT: from main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue' 
import App from './App' 
import router from './router' 

Vue.config.productionTip = false 
new Vue({ 
    el: '#app', 
    router, 
    template: '<App/>', 
    components: { App } 
})
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working?

Comment: I dont get an error message, but the image isn't showing.

Comment: I tried and it works. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/sb0tyuf8/

Comment: Strange, could the problem be that i'm running the vue-cli with its dev server?

Comment: I bet this is to do with how you create an instance of the component. Can you show us your code for that ?

Comment: can you show your main.js/app.js ?

Comment: main.js: 

`code`import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})`code`

Comment: Any idea what the problem is @JamesWestgate ?

Answer (score 0):

In a component, `Data` should always be a function